# show object array data in setInterval with localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have an object array with length 4.

```
    var employees = [
        { name: "Santosh", age:25, emp_id:23, date_of_birth: '23/10/2015'},
        { name: "jyoti", age:93, emp_id:97, date_of_birth: '14/05/2011'},
        { name: "abhishe", age:99, emp_id:96, date_of_birth: '01/11/2009'},
        { name: "Amir", age:77, emp_id:16, date_of_birth: '24/08/2005'}
    ];
```

I am showing those data as a list item.

After those 4 list item I push another array(same data - just for test) and with setInterval I am looping data in 1 minute. So every 1 minute it will display the data 1 by 1 and it will stop at 8th (4 static data + 4 setInterval data) position. But every time I refresh page it should start with the same position.

For eg: if the setInterval loop is going on and it has already displayed 2 more data and when I refresh the page it should start with the same position and stop to 8th.

I have successfully loop those data in setInterval but I don't know the logic behind how do I work with localstorage. I have a basic knowledge of localstorage.

```
function update_array_with_time(){

    employees.push(employees[3])

    var len = employees.length;
    console.log(len);

    if(len === 5) {
        employees[4] = employees[0];
    } else if(len===8) {
        employees[7] = employees[1];
        window.clearInterval(setIntv);
    }
    loop_data(4,newemp.length)
    document.getElementById("new_emp").innerHTML = text;
}
var setIntv = setInterval(update_array_with_time, 1000);
```

I want it to start from same position until I reset the time. The array should loop in every 1 minute but in my case for saving time I have loop with only 1 second.

Here the code in [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/kOdgQNBZcXyAi8bjUJ4l/)

---

[Plunker 2](https://embed.plnkr.co/uvNDrpVq3Za7zKCZNjpI/)
I have created new plunker with localstorage. But still it is refreshing data. Also before it used to start from no. 5 but now it is starting from 1.

Any idea ?

Comment: If you only have four elements of data, I'm not quite sure what you are expecting to display after that.   You speak of the 5th position and the 8th position, but you don't have that much data.

Comment: After 4 data I am keep pushing a new data called `employees.push(employees[3])` so the new data that is keep adding is the last array of the item. It is working. I have plunker too. data up to 8 will hold new array I have push.